# Can Insomnia convert an uploaded JSON to send a JSON body instead of a file?

Tags: json, insomnia

I'm attempting to send a large JSON file to the system. The endpoint is expecting a JSON body, but if I copy paste the full JSON file into a JSON body, Insomnia crashes.

I thought of doing the "Multipart" option, but the file is transmitted as is, which isn't a JSON body.

Is there any way to tell Insomnia to take the contents of the JSON file and make a JSON body with it?